# Powershell Hashtable values using variable key

Tags: powershell, variables, key, hashtable

I am trying to let a user make a selection and then return a value from a hashtable based on that selection.

My hashtable looks like this:

```
$choices = @{ 0 = "SelectionA"; 
              1 = "SelectionB"; 
              99 = "SelectionC"}
```

My selection looks like this:

```
$selection = Read-Host -Prompt "
Please make a selection
0 - Selection A
1 - Selection B
99 - Selection C "
```

Then I'm trying to bring back the value based on the selection like this:

```
$choices.$selection
```

or

```
$choices.{$selection}
```

This isn't working.  Is it possible to call a hashtable value using a variable as the key?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: `$choices.[int]$selection`

Comment: Or `$choices = @{ '0' = 'SelectionA'}` :). This is one of the PowerShell's automatic type conversion blindspots. Keys in your hashtable are integers, but `Read-Host` returns strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above are both correct answers.  I'm adding them as answers to close the question.

By [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436443/powershell-hashtable-values-using-variable-key/43983588#comment60487834_36436443):

```
$choices.[int]$selection
```

Or by [beatcracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436443/powershell-hashtable-values-using-variable-key/43983588#comment60488303_36436443):

```
$choices = @{ '0' = 'SelectionA'}
```

> This is one of the PowerShell's automatic type conversion blindspots. Keys in your hashtable are integers, but Read-Host returns strings.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Get_Item method.

```
$myChoice = $choices.Get_Item($selection)
```

You may have to convert the $selection variable into an integer first, since I believe it will come in as a string.

More info on hash tables: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx

Answer (score -1):

#### The simple works in PSVersion 7

```
$ha=@{0='aa';1='bb'}
$sel=0
$ha.$sel // 'aa'
```